# Broken apt from ignition-sensors6 unmet dependencies

Tags: package, ignition-fortress, apt

I want a version of the ignition-sensors6 package that has not yet been released. For that I used `make package` to generate a package with the name ignition-sensors6. However, I verified that when I install the currently available ignition fortress, there is no package called ignition-sensors6, but instead there are several packages with prefix libignition-sensors6. When I try to replace those packages by the one I generated, I break apt, because there are other packages, such as ignition-fortress, which depend on the libignition-sensors6 packages and don't recognize ignition-sensors6 as a valid substitute. How can I generate all the small packages of libignition-sensors6?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu (or other distribution) are you using, and what are the versions of the other ignition packages you did install?